# I've got into an error while connecting to mongodb and express and my terminal's gone mad

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here's the error. It's blowing me up. Please help.

It's just getting mad at me for something that is not supported. And it's shouting at me not supported. I've never seen that many errors in the terminal. Can anyone tell me why I am getting this.

```
  DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is 

deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
Server running on port 300
(node:6452) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseError: Can't call `openUri()` on an active connection with different connection strings. Make sure you aren't calling `mongoose.connect()` multiple times. See: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#multiple_connections    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (C:\Users\hp\Documents\short shortnner-backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:682:13)
    at C:\Users\hp\Documents\short shortnner-backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:342:10
    at C:\Users\hp\Documents\short shortnner-backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:31:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\hp\Documents\short shortnner-backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:30:10)
    at Mongoose.connect (C:\Users\hp\Documents\short shortnner-backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:341:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\hp\Documents\short shortnner-backend\models\Url.js:10:27)    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1026:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\hp\Documents\short shortnner-backend\routes\url.js:7:13) 
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
(node:6452) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:6452) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code. DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
Server running on port 300
(node:6452) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseError: Can't call `openUri()` on an active connection with different connection strings. Make sure you aren't calling `mongoose.connect()` multiple times. See: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#multiple_connections    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (C:\Users\hp\Documents\short shortnner-backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:682:13)
    at C:\Users\hp\Documents\short shortnner-backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:342:10
    at C:\Users\hp\Documents\short shortnner-backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:31:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\hp\Documents\short shortnner-backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:30:10)
    at Mongoose.connect (C:\Users\hp\Documents\short shortnner-backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:341:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\hp\Documents\short shortnner-backend\models\Url.js:10:27)    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1026:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\hp\Documents\short shortnner-backend\routes\url.js:7:13) 
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
(node:6452) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:6452) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
 MongoDB Connected...
```

Here's the link to my [code](https://github.com/dingus45191/short-shortnner-backend)

Comment: can you add the mongo connection code here?

Comment: ok  i am adding code here

Comment: https://github.com/dingus45191/short-shortnner-backend

Comment: did you white list the IPs? https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDgXF.png

Comment: yes I whitelisted all ips

Comment: try node driver older version and copy that URI. https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWArD.png

Comment: ok i am trying it thanks

Comment: did exactly what you said and now I edited the question with new errors.

Comment: now it's working, I reproduce the repo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all about mongo connection:

1. Your params passed to `mongoose.connect` in `./models/url.js` are incorrect:

The first param of `mongoose.connect` is a mongo connection string and the second is an options (passed down to mongo.connect) or a callback, which should be something like

```
module.exports = mongoose.connect('mongodb://user:pass@localhost:port/database', { useNewUrlParser: true });
```

You can find its offcial docs here: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/mongoose.html#mongoose_Mongoose-connect

2. Remember that `mongoose.connect` is an async function, using `require("../models/Url")` in `./routes/url.js` will lead to unexpected result.

Comment: I did as you said and I updated my question with new errors which I got

Comment: @Dingus45191 the warning is so clear, just pass another option `useUnifiedTopology: true` to `mongoose.connect`, the error is because of your `./routes/url.js` which use the old `./models/url.js` file, please read my answer carefully